# What is a word for a person who desires to get married, or that desire?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, adjectives

What word or words could be accurate used to express that someone strongly desires to be married? This could be in general or to a specific person, but particularly the general case.

Misogamist is used to describe someone who is adverse to marriage. I want the opposite of this. Is there a similar latin derived or clinical word like this? A traditional or casual one?

An example of misogamist usage: "Good luck with that... Morris is a misogamist. He will never want to marry anyone."

An example of my desired word usage: "Lillian, ever the ?????, has always been planning for her inevitable wedding day."

Another example of desired word usage: "Caleb, absorbed in (his) ?????, pursues romance at every opportunity."

I have checked thefreedictionary.com for words with the -gamy prefix, looked around on wikipedia's marriage related topics, looked though dictionary.com's words related to matrimony, and nothing quite fits.

An informal (and disparaging) example might be 'marriage fever'. A formal (and positive) version might be 'matrimonial aspirations'. I would prefer a clinical, psychological or otherwise least value-neutral term.

A single word or compound word is much preferred, though if a phrase is needed it must be as brief as possible.

Comment: The *romantic*?

Comment: @Lawrence Damn, you beat me to it! Literally the first word that comes to mind.

Comment: @Marcus Haha! If you don’t mind hunting around for some substantiation, feel free to post it as an answer.

Comment: The obvious pairing to _misogamist_ would be a _philogamist_. Never seen that, though (then again, have I ever seen _misogamist_? Don’t know). It may never have been coined. It’s quite transparent to anyone who knows their Greek affixes.

Comment: I've never heard misogamist in common language use, but is was easy to find online and philogamist was not. Thank you for that!

Comment: I think romantic is what is commonly used in modern language. Thank you too!